# How to monitor MySQL queries on Windows

Tags: sql, windows, mysql

Is there any easy way to track/monitor all the SQL of the queries, executed by an MySQL server (on a Windows machine)?

**Update**: I am asking about the free tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Send this command to the server:
   `set global general_log=1;`
2. Find the log file (the default on Win7 it resides in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data`) and has a name just like the computer.
3. Examine the log :)
4. Set the `general_log` back to `0` to return the DB server performance back to normal.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me on local windows 7 x64 installation of MYSQL 5.6 was:

- Open your my.ini file and make sure you have these lines:

  ## Long query log

  ```
  long_query_time = 1
  slow_query_log = 1
  slow_query_log_file = "C:\Zend\MySQL5.6\slowquery.log"
  ```

  ## Set General Log

  ```
  general_log=1
  general_log_file = "C:\Zend\MySQL5.6\genquery.log"
  ```
- Save file and restart the service

To switch off general query logs, set general_log value to 0 and restart.
And do not forget to change the paths of log files to match your system.

Comment: Note: It seems that you can omit the path and just give the filename, it will then put it in your mysql "data" folder.

Answer (score 2):

You could download a 30-day trial of: [MONyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/). If it's the tool for you, I suggest you buy it.

Comment: yep, I know about it. I am looking for a free tool (question updated).